# creating custom TableViewCell , label positions are correct

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am trying to use custom UITableViewCell. Everything is going well but the label I used in cell is not placing in proper place. I dragged labels as it is in custom cell from library. 
Cell referenced to the class in its attribute window. I have only created an empty nib. Should I create a class for cell to set its place ? Any help tutorial reference plz. Actually I am trying to create view like:   [image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]Create CustomCell and drag and drop the uilables in the custom cell then use it. [this is great one acc to ur problem](http://www.e-string.com/content/custom-uitableviewcells-interface-builder) and [here is another tutorial](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/)

added the imgae of ableview cell

Comment: @inder kumar: i was doing same!! but when i used the nib file of custome cell in method "cellatrowindex" then labels get overlapped with values in array . like 'company' label  get over lap by its value !! and when i scroll up side they got disappered

Comment: also sen the images of your overlapped labels if possible

Comment: uploaded the image and code... and how can i display each cell individually a round rect!!

Comment: bcoz cell is embedding into table view's cells i guess thats why its ovellapping bcoz cutom cell view's height is more then cell of normal table view

Comment: yeah i seem like so... just return the height of custom cell e.g. `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ return 70.0;}`

Comment: n how can i make a cell to display individually( a round rect) !! its showing in group!!

Comment: Increase the height of the CustomCell make its background clearColor ant then put a uiimageview smaller in height it will look like your cell have a gap..

Comment: i am not getting you.. i have increased the height and labels are at correct position. Where i have to put uiimageview smaller in height?

Comment: In your customcell drag n drop the uiimageview

Comment: i dragged it but not showing each cell individually .I don't understand how drag and drop of uiimageview will show that what i want?

Comment: Just make the background color of your view as clear, then add an imageview to it as shown above,either set its color or set its image. suppose imageview height is 80 then return 120 from the method heightForRowAtIndexpath:

Comment: or you can do one thing suppose you have 10 rows then make 10 sections with only one row that will show your row individually